# Building an absolute URL from a relative URL in Java

Tags: java, url, relative-url

I'm having trouble building an absolute URL from a relative URL without resorting to String hackery...

Given

```
http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/someServlet
```

Inside the method:

```
   public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
```

What's the most "correct" way of building :

```
http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/someImage.jpg
```

(Note, must be absolute, not relative)

Currently, I'm doing it through building the string, but there MUST be a better way.

I've looked at various combinations of new URI / URL, and I end up with

```
http://localhost:8080/someImage.jpg
```

Help greatly appreciated

Comment: If you don’t know how it works, how do you know it’s “really simple 101 stuff”?

Comment: It's more of a slur on my own ability than anything else.   However, I've edited to remove the comment, in case it was perceived as offensive in anyway -- which was not the intent.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using java.net.URL

```
 URL baseUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/someFolder/");
 URL url = new URL(baseUrl, "../test.html");
```

Comment: did this, ended up with the same url `http://localhost:8080/someImage.jpg` instead of `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/someImage.jpg`

Comment: It also works with: `new URL(baseUrl, "/otherFolder/test.html");` which will translate into: `http://www.google.com/otherFolder/test.html`

Comment: In order for `new URL(baseUrl, path)` to resolve properly, `baseUrl` **must** end with `/` and `path` **must** be relative (not start with `/`). At that point...you could just append the strings and it would work equally well, unless you also need `../` processing. In that **one** case, this technique makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
String s = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath() + "/someImage.jpg";
```

Comment: What if I want to build the absolute URL in a context where no request is available, for example in a scheduler thread to generate email in which a absolute URL link is put

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already figured out the hard part, which is what host your are running on. The rest is easy,

```
String url = host + request.getContextPath() + "/someImage.jpg";
```

Should give you what you need.

Answer (score -1):

this code work will on **linux**, it can **just combine the path**, if you want more, constructor of URI could be helpful.

```java
URL baseUrl = new URL("http://example.com/first");
URL targetUrl = new URL(baseUrl, Paths.get(baseUrl.getPath(), "second", "/third", "//fourth//", "fifth").toString());
```

if you path contain something need to escape, use `URLEncoder.encode` to escape it at first.

```java
URL baseUrl = new URL("http://example.com/first");
URL targetUrl = new URL(baseUrl, Paths.get(baseUrl.getPath(), URLEncoder.encode(relativePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), URLEncoder.encode(filename, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).toString());
```

example:

```java
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL baseUrl = new URL("http://example.com/first");
            Path relativePath = Paths.get(baseUrl.getPath(), "second", "/third", "//fourth//", "fifth");
            URL targetUrl = new URL(baseUrl, relativePath.toString());
            System.out.println(targetUrl.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
http://example.com/first/second/third/fourth/fifth
```

`baseUrl.getPath()` are very important, don't forget it.

a wrong example:

```java
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL baseUrl = new URL("http://example.com/first");
            Path relativePath = Paths.get("second", "/third", "//fourth//", "fifth");
            URL targetUrl = new URL(baseUrl, relativePath.toString());
            System.out.println(targetUrl.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
http://example.com/second/third/fourth/fifth
```

we have lost our `/first` in baseurl.

Comment: Paths.get() is a filesystem API. I just checked, and It uses the filesystem native separator, which is "\" on Windows.