# Creating a URL Using Java - What's the Best Practice?

Tags: java, url

I have an application that is calling a rest service.  I need to pass it a URL and right now I'm creating the URL by concatenating a string.

I'm doing it this way:

```
String urlBase = "http:/api/controller/";  
String apiMethod = "buy";
String url = urlBase + apiMethod;
```

The above is fake obviously, but the point is I'm using simple string concats.

Is this the best practice?  I'm relatively new to Java.  Should I be building a URL object instead?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498030/append-relative-url-to-java-net-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a base path which needs some additional string to be added to it you have 2 options:

First is, using `String.format()`:

```
String baseUrl = "http:/api/controller/%s"; // note the %s at the end
String apiMethod = "buy";
String url = String.format(baseUrl, apiMethod);
```

Or using `String.replace()`:

```
String baseUrl = "http:/api/controller/{apiMethod}";
String apiMethod = "buy";
String url = baseUrl.replace("\\{apiMethod}", apiMethod);
```

The nice thing about both answers is, that the string that needs to be inserted, doesn't have to be at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jersey-client. The following would be the best practice to access the subresources without making the code ugly

**Resource**: /someApp

**Sub-Resource:** /someApp/getData

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://localhost:7777/someApp/").path("getData");
    Response response = webTarget.request().header("key", "value").get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plain Java, it's better to use dedicated class for URL building which throws exception if provided data are invalid in semantic way.

It has various constructors, you can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

***Example***

```
URL url = new URL(
   "http",
   "stackoverflow.com",
   "/questions/50989746/creating-a-url-using-java-whats-the-best-practive"
);
System.out.println(url);
```