# What is the right way to safely concatenate an URL without forgetting a separator?

Tags: java, url, concatenation

lets assume I have some method like that:

```
void getMagicUrl(Sting urlBase, String addedPath) {
    urlBase = urlBase.endsWith("/") ? urlBase : urlBase + "/";      // *1*
    urlBase = urlBase + "constantPath/";                            // *2*
    urlBase = urlBase + addedPath;                                  // *3*
    return new URL(urlBase);                                        // *4*
}
```

Is there with Java (8) no better way to concatenate the URL together and not to check manual for the ending / as path separator to not forget it? (Like in line *1*)
and have it in the path names always? (like in line *2*)

or does the JDK have something in there?

Comment: What do you not like about your approach?

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate this constructor that's already in URL? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: @Wow: I always have to check to not forget the "/" and if an url is passed to a method check if it is there. always!

Comment: @ControlAltDel: no, this is just an example - I always have to do this not only on construction.

Comment: @PaulEdison I don't think there's such a thing in the JDK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a URL Using Java - What's the Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989746/creating-a-url-using-java-whats-the-best-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more alternatives to build a url in both type-safety and fluent way. They involve adding new dependencies but some of them are very common and useful.

**Apache commons** ([JavaDoc](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html))

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setHost("your_host")
        .setPath("/you_path")
        .setParameter("param1", "value1")
        .build();

uri.toString();
```

**JAX-RS** ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html))

```
URI uri= UriBuilder
    .fromPath("your_domain")
    .scheme("http")
    .path("your_path/")
    .queryParam("param1", "value1")
    .build();

URI uri = builder.build();
```

**OkHttp** ([JavaDoc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/)) ([GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp))

```
URL url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
        .scheme("http")
        .host("your_domain")
        .addPathSegments("your_path")
        .addQueryParameter("param1", "value1")
        .build()
        .url();
```

If you want to use Java 8 without additional dependencies, you could use URI class' constructor directly but it's not so friendly as the previous alternatives.

**URI class** ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html))

```
URI uri = new URI("your_host", "your_path", "param1=value1");
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the most efficient ways to build url is to use [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html)

Something like this

```
 UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
      .scheme("http").host("www.blahblah.com).path("/somepath").build().encode();

 uriComponents.toUriString());
```

This avoids all the manual concatenation using `+`

There are many methods to add path variables and query params and much more. [Here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder) is a nice article on it.

Comment: But it is not part of JDK :( I don't add just for that another lib (especially as the app has to be downloaded)