# How to get absolute url from the relative url in java

Tags: url, web-crawler, relative-url

I am having a page like mypage.com/a/b/somePage.html, and one of the anchors href attribute is something like "a/b/anotherPage.html".

When i try to get the absolute url from by creating a new  url object with page url and href value, i am getting the absolute url as mypage.com/a/b/a/b/anotherPage.html.

This is causing problem for me, but some how the browsers are handling this properly.

Any out of box things available to solve this problem. ( I can always add an exception in the code to  handle this differently, but i don't want to do this.)

Comment: Try something like ` URL url = new URL( new URL("http://www.google.com/a/b/page.html") , "a/b/page2.html");
     System.out.println(url);  `

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building an absolute URL from a relative URL in Java servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389184/building-an-absolute-url-from-a-relative-url-in-java-servlet)

Answer (score 3):

Using java.net.URL

```
URL baseUrl = new URL("http:www.google.com/someFolder/");
URL url = new URL( baseURL , "../test.html");
```