# Converting window.open(Hyperlink) Javascript code to pure absolute url with JAVA

Tags: java, javascript, onclick, jsoup, window.open

I work on a website  with JAVA Jsoup Library to extract some hyperlinks

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.saudisale.com/SS_a_mpg.aspx").get();
Elements script = doc.select("script") ;  

for(Element elementary :doc.select("table"))
{
System.out.println(""+elementary.select("tbody").select("tr").select("td").select("input").attr("onClick")+"");
```

Sample Output:-

```
window.open('http://saudisale.com/arPrivatePage.aspx?id=21871638','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
window.open('http://saudisale.com/arPrivatePage.aspx?id=21871638','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
window.open('http://saudisale.com/arPrivatePage.aspx?id=21871638','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
window.open('http://ads.saudisale.com/dyaralez.html ','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
window.open('http://ads.saudisale.com/dyaralez.html ','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');


window.open('http://ads.saudisale.com/dalel.html','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');

window.open('http://ads.saudisale.com/dalel.html','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
    window.open('SS_a_car.aspx?carid=37240','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
    window.open('SS_a_car.aspx?carid=37240','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
```

Based on the fact that  Jsoup does not support javascript, so I have to do some manual java code to convert window.open(hyperlink ) javascript code  to absolute hyperlink

For example the following output JavaScript code  has to be converted

```
window.open('http://saudisale.com/arPrivatePage.aspx?id=21871638','_blank','channelmode=1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1')
```

To:
  http://saudisale.com/arPrivatePage.aspx?id=21871638

and

```
window.open('SS_a_car.aspx?carid=37149','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');
```

To
    http://www.saudisale.com/SS_a_car.aspx?carid=37149

Could someone guide me how to accomplish this task with JAVA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex. This will do what you want:

```
String input = "window.open('http://saudisale.com/arPrivatePage.aspx?id=21871638','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1');";

String regex = "window.open\\(['\"]*(.*?)(\\s*['\"]*,.*?)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {

    String output = (matcher.group().replaceAll(regex, "$1"));
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Your last two URLs are *relative*, so you have to convert them to absolute URLs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389184/building-an-absolute-url-from-a-relative-url-in-java).

Comment: Your code works fine, for the second URL I tried the following code String input2 ="window.open('SS_a_car.aspx?carid=37149','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1')";   
 
 URL baseURL = new URL("http://saudisale.com/");
 URL url = new URL( baseURL ,input2);
 System.out.printl(url);  But it doesn't give the desired output any more help please?

Comment: @JavaFan,  Use `http://saudisale.com/` as your baseURL. You must include the `http://` part at the the beginning. Try that, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For relative URl I used this code. It works fine.

```
String input2 = "window.open('SS_a_car.aspx?carid=37149','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1')";        

    URL baseURL = new URL("http://saudisale.com/");

    String regex = "window.open\\(['\"]*(.*?)(\\s*['\"]*,.*?)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input2);
    while (matcher.find()) {

        String output = (matcher.group().replaceAll(regex, "$1"));
        URL url = new URL( baseURL ,output);
        System.out.println(url);
    }
```