# JSOUP extracting absolute url from html

Tags: java, android, url, jsoup, href

I've been looking on jsoup page, but all I could do was extract titles and so on from url... but I need whole absolute url address from exact div. I want to store it somewhere and use it later.

```
<div class="link-block container">
                <a href="/what-to-do/11636002" rel="nofollow" 
                        title="unique abilities" class="just-link">
                </a>
</div>
```

As I said, I tried `String absHref = link.attr("abs:href")`, but it gave me the "title" part from the code. What I am doing wrong? Please give me some advice.

Comment: Show us your code implementation.

Comment: For getting absolute url from some part of it you need to use a regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326901/converting-window-openhyperlink-javascript-code-to-pure-absolute-url-with-java

Comment: I found quite simple way:  URL baseUrl = new URL("my base url");
   URL url = new URL(baseUrl, "/what-to-do/11636002");      and it works fine, because I have got an absolute link at the end. Now just tell me guys how to extract the "/what-to-do/11636002" part using for example jsoup ??

Comment: If some answer worked for you then you should accept it. Else, if you have later found out a better solution to the problem, you can answer your own question and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
String myHtml = "<div class=\"link-block container\">\n"
                + "  <a href=\"/what-to-do/11636002\" rel=\"nofollow\" title=\"unique abilities\" class=\"just-link\">\n"
                + "  </a>\n"
                + "</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(myHtml, "http://your.baseurl");
Element e = doc.select("a").first();

System.out.println(e.attr("abs:href"));
```

Prints:

```
http://your.baseurl/what-to-do/11636002
```

---

If you want to get all `a` Elements which are similar, do:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("a[href*=/what-to-do/");
for (Element e: elements) {
   System.out.println(e.attr("abs:href"));
}
```

This will get you all `a` with `href` containing "/what-to-do/".

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to get exactly this part into my variable (for example myHtml). That was my question.

Comment: @edinson From where do you want to get it ? If you have myHtml as a String, then you should parse it as in my answer. If it's from a URL, use `Jsoup.connect(yourUrl).get();` or do you mean something else ? It's not quite clear to me.

Comment: I have got a whole HTML site. And from the whole site' code I need to extract the "/what-to-do/11636002" part. So it is not the only one url in the code.

Comment: @edinson, Just select all `a` Elements from the page which you want. I've updated my answer.