# How to extract the relative url from the absolute url in Java

Tags: java

I have this website:

```
https://asd.com/somestuff/another.html
```

and I want to extract the relative part out of it:

```
somestuff/another.html
```

How do I do that?

EDIT: I was offered an answer to a question, but the problem there was to build the absolute url out of the relative which is not what I'm interested in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building an absolute URL from a relative URL in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389184/building-an-absolute-url-from-a-relative-url-in-java)

Comment: Not a duplicate, they want the opposite thing there

Comment: Sorry my mistake... Find your answer here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/ResolvearelativeURLstringagainstanabsoluteURLstring.htm

Comment: @J.K. According to your new edit. Where are you going to trying to retrieve the absolute path if it is not from your relative website?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [`getPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath()) method of the `URL` object:

```
URL url = new URL("https://asd.com/somestuff/another.html");
System.out.println(url.getPath());  // prints "/somestuff/another.html"
```

Now, this only brings the actual path. If you need more information (the anchor or the parameters passed as get values), you need to call other accessors of the `URL` object:

```
URL url = new URL("https://asd.com/somestuff/another.html?param=value#anchor");
System.out.println(url.getPath());  // prints "/somestuff/another.html"
System.out.println(url.getQuery()); // prints "param=value"
System.out.println(url.getRef());   // prints "anchor"
```

A possible use to generate the relative URL without much code, based on [Hiru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30844342/1734119):

```
URL absolute = new URL(url, "/");
String relative = url.toString().substring(absolute.toString().length());
System.out.println(relative); // prints "somestuff/another.html?param=value#anchor"
```

Comment: very brief description!! +1 @Chop

Answer (score 2):

if you know that the domain will always be .com then you can try something like this:

```
String url = "https://asd.com/somestuff/another.html";
String[] parts = url.split(".com/");
//parts[1] is the string after the .com/
```

Comment: it would be .com specific.. what if its "https://asd.in/somestuff/another.html" or something else

Comment: @Hiru This response assumes that `url` contains "XXX.com".

Answer (score 1):

The URL consists of the following elements (note that some optional elements are omitted):
1) scheme
2) hostname
3) [port]
4) path
5) query
6) fragment
Using the [Java URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) API, you can do the following:

```
URL u = new URL("https://randomsite.org/another/randomPage.html");
System.out.println(u.getPath());
```

Edit#1
Seeing Chop's answer, in case you have query elements in your URL, such as

```
?name=foo&value=bar
```

Using the `getQuery()` method will not return the resource path, just the query part.

Comment: Yep, I was mistaken and made a test to make sure I was not giving bad advice. I also included more details about `getQuery()` and `getRef()` before seeing your answer. Great minds think alike. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

Use it Globally not only for .com

```
    URL u=new URL("https://asd.in/somestuff/another.html");
    String u1=new URL(u, "/").toString();
    String u2=u.toString();
    String[] u3=u2.split(u1);
    System.out.println(u3[1]); //it prints:   somestuff/another.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using below snippet.

```
 String str="https://asd.org/somestuff/another.html";
    if(str.contains("//")) //To remove any protocol specific header.
    {
        str=str.split("//")[1];
    }
    System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf("/")+1)); // taking the first '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on `java.net.URI`

```
URI _absoluteURL = new URI(absoluteUrl).normalize();
String root = _absoluteURL.getScheme() + "://" + _absoluteURL.getAuthority();
URI relative = new URI(root).relativize(_absoluteURL);

String result = relative.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Apache Commons VFS...

```java
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.VFS;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory;

public class StudyURI {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, FileSystemException {
        StandardFileSystemManager fileSystemManager = (StandardFileSystemManager) VFS.getManager();
        URLStreamHandlerFactory factory = fileSystemManager.getURLStreamHandlerFactory();
        URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(factory);

        URI baseURI = fileSystemManager.resolveFile("https://asd.com/").getURI();
        URI anotherURI =fileSystemManager.resolveFile("https://asd.com/somestuff/another.html").getURI();

        String result = baseURI.relativize(anotherURI).getPath();

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Maybe you need to add module to run the code:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient