# Selenium driver.getPageSource() ,change links to absolute

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, pdf

I am trying to get page source in selenium using

```
String ps = driver.getPageSource();
```

but links inside page source are relative,like

```
<img src="images/cgglogogogo.png">
```

Because of this I cannot use this source code as images/css are not displaying,I want to use this source code to render a pdf. Please help

Comment: by "incomplete" you mean the link paths are relative? how do you intend to use the page source to render a PDF?

Comment: @EliranMalka Yeah paths are relative and I want to convert it into absolute path

Comment: @EliranMalka I will either use PhantomJs or wkhtmltopdf(java wrapper class) to render it into pdf

Comment: you'd have to process the page source, look into `driver.getCurrentUrl()` to get the base URL (than you can concat it with the relative URLs on the page).

Comment: @EliranMalka Ok that's great,but there will paths like  `../..images/cgg.png`,how to deal with those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.net.URL;
URL baseUrl = new URL("http:www.example.com/someFolder/");
URL url = new URL( baseUrl , "../..images/cgg.png");
```

This worked for me!

Please refer this:
[Building an absolute URL from a relative URL in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389184/building-an-absolute-url-from-a-relative-url-in-java)